# Windows 10 - Can I reset local password using my Microsoft Account?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, dell-inspiron

I bought my `Dell 7577` 1 month ago, it has `Windows 10 - Home Single Language` OS. I added my `Microsoft Account` and use `PIN` to sign in to my laptop.

Now I tried to sign in using a `Password` and it's says incorrect. I remember that the password I created is same as in my Microsoft Account but now it's incorrect.

I go to the official website of Microsoft and tried to sign in and the password is correct.

I can't reset it using the `PIN` as security, there's no way I can reset it via this thing called `USB-Re-setter` because I didn't make any before this happen, I also don't want to reset everything for the sake of files and software I have.

The only thing I can think of is to sign-in into the official website of Microsoft and try to reset the password but I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: You can try [WindowsVaultPasswordDecryptor](https://securityxploded.com/windows-vault-password-decryptor.php). It would show you password if ever saved in browser or vault. You may always reset your password through official website using your recovery email/phone number.

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing I can think of is to sign-in into the official website
> of Microsoft and try to reset the password but I don't know if it is
> possible.

It is indeed possible.

> 1. On the sign-in screen, type your Microsoft account name if it's not displayed. If there are multiple accounts on the PC, choose the one to reset.
> 2. Select **I forgot my password** below the password text box.
> 3. On the Recover your account screen, type the characters displayed in the box below **Enter the characters you see**, then select **Next**.
> 4. On the Verify your identity screen, choose to receive your security code either as a text or email message. If you choose text, type the last four digits of your phone number, and then select **Send code**. [Learn more about security info and security codes.](https://support.microsoft.com/help/12428)
> 5. When you get the code as a text or email message on a separate device, enter it and then select **Next**.
> 6. On the Reset your password screen, create a new password, and then select **Next**. This sets your new password. Select Next again to return to the sign-in screen.
> 7. Sign in with your new Microsoft account password.

An alternative solution is to disconnect your Microsoft account, and switching your profile to a local profile, allowing you to set a new password to the profile.  You could at this point, after you complete that process, reconnect your Microsoft Account to your profile.

You should also verify you are not using a proxy or any other configuration that is resulting in a communication issue with Microsoft.

Source: [How to reset your Microsoft account password](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026971/microsoft-account-how-to-reset-your-password)

Answer (score 0):

Use the procedure described in the section "Windows 10 PC" of the Microsoft article
[How to reset your Microsoft account password](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026971/microsoft-account-how-to-reset-your-password).